# HTML input button appears different in iPad

Tags: ipad, html, css

I've created HTML input.

```
<input type="submit" id="Submitbtn" onclick="javascript:function()" value="Login" name="Submitbtn">
```

CSS is:

```
input:hover, input{
     background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #1356B4;
     border: medium none;
     margin-right: 0;
     padding: 3px 10px 5px 0;
     vertical-align: middle;
     border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
     color: #FFFFFF;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: inline-block;
     font: 14px/26px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
     height: 26px;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

The output in web browsers:

[image]

And in iPad:

[image]

How to resolve this?

Comment: Please show us your css element name(s) for all relevant css. ie "#SubmitBtn { ... css ...} Thanks.

Comment: I've edited my question and added css

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle.net page, or a demo page for this? I am getting different colors and appearances again, but this may be because of incomplete CSS provided in the question... (Still getting unexpected appearance - http://jsfiddle.net/lucanos/nTF4U/1/)

Comment: yes color is different in code, the main issue is I want to avoid the default behavior of button. It currently looks like button inside a button.

Comment: If you will see your JSFiddle code, even it appears differently in iPad. :( want the same appearance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose you must get rid of the webkit appearance on your button by adding in your CSS:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Comment: remember to put that inside an ´input['type=submit']´, not just general input{}, otherwise you'll mess up your radio input fields under webkit.

Comment: Btw: You can regress webkit-issues like these on your desktop machine, using google chrome, since it is also a webkit browser.